# JSON Output in Javascript to HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON output as below

```
{
   "556520000":{
      "lmin":"35",
      "dm":[
         {
            "Width":"147"
         },
         {
            "Depth":"10"
         },
         {
            "Height":"137"
         }
      ],
      "lmax":"68",
   }
}
```

I'm trying to output the dm key, into html so I get something like

```
<span id="sku_DM">
<ul>
<li><span>A</span> Width: 147</li>
<li><span>B</span> Depth: 10</li>
<li><span>C</span> Height: 137</li>
</ul>
</span>
```

The JS I have so far outputs to console ok, but when I try and to output as HTML in ID #sku_DM it just puts the last value rather than what I have in the console. My JS code is below

```
var SKU = "556520000";
var dimBreak = obj[SKU]["dm"];
for(var i = 0; i < dimBreak.length; i++){
    const dimAll = dimBreak[i];
    let entries = Object.entries(dimAll);
    
    for(const [prop, val] of entries) {
        console.log(prop, val);
        var fullDimensions = (prop, val);
        document.getElementById("sku_DM").innerHTML = fullDimensions;
    }
}
```

Would appreciate some help on this.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `innerHTML += fullDimensions`? *Notice the + symbol in conjunction with =*

Comment: Looks like you are overwriting `innerHTML` per loop cycle. .... On a separate note it looks like you are expecting some "magic" to happen on formatting of the html.

Comment: What were you hoping this would do? `var fullDimensions = (prop, val);` I'm pretty sure it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: Changing it to innerHTML += fullDimensions only gives me the sizes but not the keys. var fullDimensions = (prop,val) doesn't work. That's what I'm not clear, what does it need to be instead as the console outputs it ok. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map over the `dimBreak` array and create the required html markup. After that, you can inject the generated html markup in the `DOM`.

**P.S.** As `.map()` function returns an array, before inserting the generated html string in the `DOM`, call `.join()` function on the returned array to combine all the array elements in one string.

```js
const obj = {
  "556520000": {
    "lmin": "35",
    "dm": [
      { "Width": "147" },
      { "Depth": "10" },
      { "Height": "137" }
    ],
    "lmax": "68",
  }
};

var SKU = "556520000";
var dimBreak = obj[SKU]["dm"];

let charCode = 65; // A
const html = dimBreak.map(obj => {
  const [key, value] = Object.entries(obj).flat();
  return `
     <li>
       <span>${String.fromCharCode(charCode++)}</span>
       ${key}: ${value}
     </li>
  `;
});

const list = document.querySelector('#sku_DM ul');
list.innerHTML = html.join('');
```

```html
<span id="sku_DM">
  <ul>
  </ul>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's spot on and just what I needed, really appreciate your help. Saved me some valuable time.

Comment: Thanks for the update on .join, statement. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

From your words, I understand that you don't need anything fancy nor any type of data manipulation while rendering. Why not use some good-old `pre` HTML tag?

```js
const data = {
   "556520000": {
      "lmin":"35",
      "dm":[
         {
            "Width":"147"
         },
         {
            "Depth":"10"
         },
         {
            "Height":"137"
         }
      ],
      "lmax":"68",
   }
}

const dmset = Object.values(data).map(({ dm }) => dm)

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dmset, null, 2)
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```